# How to mock the elastic search SDK for go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, elasticsearch

I'm developing an api in go, which communicates with elastic search using SDK v8.
But I'm having difficulty simulating elastic methods for unit tests

I have the following function:

```golang
func DocumentExists(id string) (bool, error) {
  exists, err := elastic.Client.Exists("my_index", "doc_id")
  if err != nil {
    return false, err
  }
  if exists.StatusCode != 200 {
    return false, nil
  }

  return true, nil
}
```

This function only checks if a document exists in elastic.
`elastic.Client` is provided globally for use anywhere in the application and has this type:

```golang
import  elastic "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
var (
  Client             *elastic.Client
)
```

You can try to mock in different ways, using mock to testify. Unsuccessfully.

How could I do this? Should I change the way I obtain the Client? Using contracts?

It seems to me that using contracts would not be necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [example](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/_examples/xkcdsearch/store_test.go) in the Elasticsearch Go client's GitHub repository demonstrates how to create a mock for the Elasticsearch client. This process primarily entails invoking `NewClient` with a configuration that substitutes the HTTP transport.

```golang
type MockTransport struct {
    Response    *http.Response
    RoundTripFn func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

func (t *MockTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return t.RoundTripFn(req)
}

func TestStore(t *testing.T) {
    mockTransport := MockTransport{
        Response: &http.Response{
            StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
            Body:       io.NopCloser(strings.NewReader(`{}`)),
            Header:     http.Header{"X-Elastic-Product": []string{"Elasticsearch"}},
        },
    }
    mockTransport.RoundTripFn = func(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) { return mockTransport.Response, nil }

    client, err := elasticsearch.NewClient(elasticsearch.Config{
        Transport: &mockTransport,
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error creating Elasticsearch client: %s", err)
    }
    // Now you can use the client for testing.
}
```